# How can I convert this string to a date 21/08/2008 00:21:00?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I'm using vb.net 2005.

How do convert this date / time 21/08/2008 00:21:00 to a DateTime object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using vb.net not c#, my solutions a bit old, but it works

```
    Dim d1 As Date
    d1 = CDate("21/08/2008 00:21:00")
    Console.WriteLine(d1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [custom date time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in conjuction with `DateTime.ParseExact` or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

```
Dim dateTime as DateTime = _
     DateTime.ParseExact("21/08/2008 00:21:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", _ 
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: `var` in VB - I think not! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim d as DateTime = DateTime.Parse("21/08/2008 00:21:00")
Console.WriteLine(d)
```

produces this:

```
21/08/2008 12:21:00 a.m.
```

Comment: Which may fail if the culture of the computer running this is `fr-FR`, for example.

Comment: true. but there is no mention of culture requirements in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure to parse that format correctly, you should use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) matching your pattern (e.g. `dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm:ss`).